# Как декодировать json c кириллицей внутри

Tags: flask, python, json, парсер

Как декодировать json файл с кириллицей внутри с помощью flask/python. Данные с файла:

```
{"data": [{"\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e-     \u0424\u0440\u0430\u043d\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0440-    \u043d", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435": "288.00"}, 
....]

  "structure": ["\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"]}
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
import json

list = [...]
data = json.dumps(list)
print 'Json: %s' % data

# Convert json to python object

new_obj = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
print 'Python obj: %s' % new_obj
```

Comment: так а что вам тут decode('string-escape') или decode("unicode_escape") от версии питона зависит. Только мне кажется, для каждого конкретного элемента надо будет делать, а не для самого json объекта.

Comment: python 2.7, то есть нужно нужно в цикле сделать?

Comment: @binliz: использование `.decode('string-escape')` c json-строкой -- это почти всегда ошибка.

Comment: @arcs_host, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если `data` это json-текст (результат `json.dumps()`), то никаких преобразований делать не нужно:

```
obj = json.loads(data)
```

json поддерживает все возможные Юникодные символы, включая русские буквы.

И не нужно на `print` ориентироваться -- это только запутает: чтобы правильно понять, что происходит, необходимо чётко представлять разницу между `str(obj)` и `repr(obj)`, а также понимать разницу между строковыми константами в Питоне и json-строками -- они могут выглядеть похоже, но это разные вещи.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(u"\N{EURO SIGN}")
'"\\u20ac"'
>>> s = u"\N{EURO SIGN}" # Строковая константа в Питоне
>>> print s
€
>>> print repr(s) # repr() это как строка в исходном коде может выглядеть
u'\u20ac'
>>> s # по умолчанию REPL использует repr()
u'\u20ac'
>>> repr(s) # представление представления repr(repr(s))
"u'\\u20ac'"
>>> s == u'\u20ac'
True
>>> data = json.dumps(s)
>>> data # json-текст 
'"\\u20ac"' # <- слэш в строковом объекте
>>> json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False)
u'"\u20ac"' # *нет* слэша в строковом объекте
>>> print json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False)
"€"         # отсутствие слэша более очевидно
>>> json.loads(data)
u'\u20ac'
>>> print json.loads(data)
€
```